# To print out unique patterns from a list using Python

Tags: python, list, unique, traversal

Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Below is my code that finds the triplets. I couldn't find a solution to remove duplicate triplets pattern

Say if I/P is -1 0 1 0
the output must only be [[-1,0,1]] but what I get is [[1,-1,0],[0,-1,1]] ....any thoughts?

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        
        result = []
        
        for i in range (2, len(nums)):
            # i,j and k will be the pointers to the list
            k = i - 1
            j = i - 2
            for k in range (k, 0, -1):
                for j in range (j, -1, -1):

                    # verify if the summation is 0
                    if j < k and nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]== 0:
                        result.append([nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]])
    
        unique_list = []
        # logic to find unique list elements
        # this works only when the list patterns are same
        for x in result:
            if x not in unique_list:
                unique_list.append(x)
        
        return unique_list
```

Comment: This is a question from leetcode : [Code](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=)

Comment: Yes a practice question...though there are number of solutions in the site just trying to solve the last part of my code :-)

Comment: Leetcode has discussions on the site. There is more info there than you can get here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```
for x in result:
    if sorted(x, key=int) not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(sorted(x, key=int))

return unique_list
```

Like this all identical (but permuted) triplets are set with same sorting, so you won't get them twice.

To answer user's comment:

```
result = [[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 1, 0]]

unique_list = []

for x in result:
    if sorted(x, key=int) not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(sorted(x, key=int))

print (unique_list)

result = [[1, -1, 0], [1, 0, -1]]

unique_list = []

for x in result:
    if sorted(x, key=int) not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(sorted(x, key=int))

print (unique_list)
```

Output:

```
[[-1, 0, 1]] #print 1
[[-1, 0, 1]] #print 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this code still fails with certain test cases. It was able to sort for [[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 1, 0]] but not on [[1, -1, 0], [1, 0, -1]]

Comment: Just a note for others this is not a optimized solution as this takes O(n^3) can try this with BST

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Synthase's post, if you sort each value of the array, the ones with the same values will be identical, if you know what I mean. To sort a value, all you have to do if use `sorted(element)`.

This is how I sorted each element in the list:

```python
sorted_list = []

for i in result:
    sorted_list.append(sorted(i))
```

This adds the sorted value of i to a new list for every item in result. Then, all we have to do is get rid of the duplicates.

This is how I deleted the duplicates:

```python
unique_list = []

for i in sorted_list:
        if i not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(i)
```

To put it all together, this is how I would write the function threeSum:

```python
def threeSum(nums):
    
    result = []
    
    for i in range (2, len(nums)):
        # i,j and k will be the pointers to the list
        k = i - 1
        j = i - 2
        for k in range (k, 0, -1):
            for j in range (j, -1, -1):

                # verify if the summation is 0
                if j < k and nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]== 0:
                    result.append([nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]])

    sorted_list = []
    unique_list = []

    for i in result:
        sorted_list.append(sorted(i))

    for i in sorted_list:
        if i not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(i)
    
    return unique_list
```